# How can I make an inoremap that calls a function

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode

I am very used to the shell autocompletion, which uses the `<tab>` character.  Therefore I tried to build something similar into my `.vimrc`. I'm aware of the super popular YCM plugin but let's face this as an exercise in learning.

I have built the following piece of vimscript to: first, allow me to use different types of `<c-x>` completions by changing a variable; second, do not fire a completion if the cursor is not after a cword character.

```
let g:tab_completion_keys = "\<c-x>\<c-p>"
function! TabCompletion1()
  let l:char = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')
  if l:char =~# '\k'
    execute "normal! a" . g:tab_completion_keys . "\<esc>"
  else
    execute "normal! a\<tab>\<esc>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <esc>:call TabCompletion1()<cr>a
```

The problem is that I cannot leave `normal!` in insert-mode.  i.e. I cannot enter insert-mode in `normal!` and finish the command without exiting the insert-mode.  Thanks to that, the code above opens the completion list and always selects the first completion, because I leave the insert mode.

How can I make an insert-mode mapping that leaves me in insert-mode for some time (to select one word from the completion list) and then continues the mapping?

Or, maybe, there is a better way to deal with `exe normal!`?

Comment: Didn't you try supertab plugin?

Comment: I second the recommendation for supertab.  To answer your question: see `:h :map-<expr>`.  Most `imap` maps are easier to write with `<expr>`.

Comment: Take a look at how [VimCompletesMe](https://github.com/ajh17/VimCompletesMe/blob/master/plugin/VimCompletesMe.vim) does that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura - Yup `:h map-<expr>` clarified a lot of things for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Sato Katsura said, this is a job for the map modifier `<expr>`.  With `<expr>` you can return the key combination from the function.  The final code looks as this:

```
let g:tab_completion_keys = "\<c-x>\<c-p>"
function! TabCompletion()
  let l:col = max([col('.')-1, 1])
  let l:char = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . l:col . 'c.')
  if l:char =~# '\k'
    return g:tab_completion_keys
  else
    return "\<tab>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <tab> TabCompletion()
```

---

In practice it is much better to use a full plugin.  I am now using [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) suggested by SibiCoder.

supertab has many more configuration options than the code above, including: defined patterns for which no completion shall be attempted, different completion contexts based on the text around the cursor and even an option to use a different key than
`<tab>`.